# Why can't I save object in Session

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
_httpContext.Session["HistoryviewModel"] = viewModel;
```

my error is:

Error   CS0021  Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'ISession'

Comment: Is this asp.net core? If so look at the type documentation [`ISession`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.isession?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you work with an `ASP.NET Core` application and you need to save in a session an instance of your customized type please consider the following solution. The solution is tested with an `ASP.NET Core` `MVC` application:

1. In the `Startup.cs` file add in the method `Configure` for the variable `app` of type 
   `IApplicationBuilder` this code:

   ```
   app.UseSession();
   ```
2. Register a service for sessions in the `Startup.cs` file, in the method 
   `ConfigureServices` using the `services` variable:

   ```
   services.AddSession();
   ```
3. Install using `NuGet` the package `System.Text.Json`
4. In my `ASP.NET Core` application, in the `cs` file with `MVC` controllers, I add:

   ```
   using System.Text.Json;
   using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
   ```

   In this file, in the namespace with `MVC` controllers, I add the following type that 
   will perform the necessary actions to set and get my object from a session:

   ```
   public static class SessionExtensions
   {
       public static void SetObjectAsJson<T>(this ISession session, string key, T value)
       {
           session.SetString(key, JsonSerializer.Serialize<T>(value));
       }

       public static object GetObjectFromJson<T>(this ISession session, string key)
       {
           var value = session.GetString(key);
           return value == null ? default(T) : JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(value);
       }
   }
   ```

   Also, I add a custom type that I will save in the session:

   ```
   public class MyClass {
       public int MyInt { get; set; }
       public string MyString { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   Now, in the first controller I put to a session an instance of the custom type:

   ```
     var myComplexObject = new MyClass();
     myComplexObject.MyInt = 1;
     myComplexObject.MyString = "Hello World!";
     HttpContext.Session.SetObjectAsJson<MyClass>("Test", myComplexObject);
   ```

   In the second controller I get this instance from the session:

   ```
   var myComplexObject = HttpContext.Session.GetObjectFromJson<MyClass>("Test");
   ```

I hope this solution helps.

Comment: Can also be written to avoid any explicit cast

`
public static T GetObjectFromJson<T>(this ISession session, string key)
    {
        var value = session.GetString(key);
        return value == null ? default(T) : JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(value);
    }
`